# Not a constant initializer element?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-construction, semantics

I encountered a confusing case when I was doing semantic analysis for my compiler course.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = "abcd"[2];

int main()
{
    char b = "abcd"[2];

    printf("%d\n%c\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

GCC says "error: initializer element is not constant" for variable "a".

Why?

Comment: Looks like a gcc quirk - [clang is quite happy with it](https://godbolt.org/g/0CPrpX), and so is [Intel's ICC](https://godbolt.org/g/JGL3nL).

Comment: @PaulR From looking at the assembly, clang doesn't treat it as a constant expression though (the value is calculated at the beginning of main and then stored in the variable). So it looks like clang dropped the standard's requirement that global initializers need to be static.

Comment: it compiled for me in vs and printed 99 c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C language requires initializers for global variables to be constant expressions. The motivation behind this is for the compiler to be able to compute the expression at compile time and write the computed value into the generated object file.

[The C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A272%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D) provides specific rules for what is a constant expression:

> 6. An
>      integer constant  expression<sup>117)</sup>
>      shall  have  integer  type  and  shall  only  have  operands
>      that   are   integer   constants,   enumeration   constants,   character   constants,
>      `sizeof`
>      expressions  whose  results  are  integer  constants,
>      `_Alignof`
>      expressions,  and  floating
>      constants that are the immediate operands of casts.  Cast operators in an integer constant
>      expression  shall  only  convert  arithmetic  types  to  integer  types,  except  as  part  of  an
>      operand to the
>      `sizeof`
>      or
>      `_Alignof`
>      operator
>      .
> 7. More  latitude  is  permitted  for  constant  expressions  in  initializers.   Such  a  constant
>      expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the following:
>
>    - an arithmetic constant expression,
>    - a null pointer constant,
>    - an address constant, or
>    - an  address  constant  for  a  complete  object  type  plus  or  minus  an  integer  constant
>        expression.

As you can see non of the cases include an array access expression or a pointer dereference. So `"abcd"[2]` does not qualify as a constant expression per the standard.

Now the standard also says:

> 10. An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.

So it would not violate the standard to allow `"abcd"[1]` as a constant expression, but it's also not guaranteed to be allowed.

So it's up to you whether or not to allow it in your compiler. It will be standard compliant either way (though allowing it is more work as you need another case in your `isConstantExpression` check and you need to actually be able to evaluate the expression at compile time, so I'd go with disallowing it).

Answer (score 0):

int a = "abcd"[2];

a is a global variable initilize at compile time but the "abcd"[2] is computed at run time.

char b = "abcd"[2];

here b is local variable and it initilize at run time after "abcd"[2] computed.